# setcookie not working php

Tags: php, google-translate, setcookie

I want to set a cookie whose value is coming from a variable and it is not working (it is not translating the page). Here is my code:

```
$store_view_aw=array();
$store_view_aw=explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$store_view=trim($store_view_aw[2]);
setcookie("googtrans", "", time()-3600,'/','');
setcookie("googtrans", "", time()-3600,'/','.domain.com');
if($store_view=='es'){
 setcookie("googtrans","/en/es", time()+3600, "/",'.domain.com');
}
```

But if on line number 3 I use some static value then it works(i.e it translates the page) ex:

```
$store_view='es';
```

I have printed their data type also using var_dump() it is same for both static and dynamic variable. 
I also tried using ob_start() and ob_end_flush(); but that also didn't worked. I am totally stucked here, please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, we need more code, especially the code prior to the setcookie(); function. Remember that no output can be send to the browser before this function.

Comment: I have used no echo or print before this function. This is all I have php code in whole file. Remaining is the html part and javascript code:                 <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement(
        {pageLanguage: 'en', autoDisplay: true}, 
        'google_translate_element'
    );  
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

Accomodations

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`?

Comment: it is string(13) "/prod_dev/es/" .

Comment: can we use echo after setcookie is used?

Comment: There might be something I don't fully understand here, but the value of the cookie NEVER comes from your dynamic variable. Looking into the issue, I'd say the problem you have is that the "if" is never met when you're using a dynamic variable to set your "store_view". I would believe your issue is with the "if" more than anything. If you echo or dump "store_view" before you test it, what's in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 setcookie ( "googtrans" , "/en/es" , time ()+ 3600 ,  "/");
```

Comment: This will only work for local but not on live server (i.e. without '.domain.com')